# Raydium Swap -- Program log: Error: The amm account owner is not match with this program

Tags: python, swap, raydium, solana-py

Getting this error when attempting a swap on Raydium within the first few seconds of a pool being created.

`"Program log: Error: The amm account owner is not match with this program`

`"Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program error: 0x1b"`

Looking at the source code for raydium-amm isn't really helpful

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/blob/master/program/src/error.rs

If I wait 20s or so after the pool is created, there is no issue with the swap, so I know the keys I am using for the transaction are correct.
For this use case swapping within the first few seconds are critical, so waiting is not a viable option.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

FB

Comment: How exactly do you send a transaction?
Is the endpoint working well?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your client is using the `Finalized` confirmation, so the second transaction is simulated against the `Finalized` block, which does not contain the newly created pool. A block typically takes 12 seconds to get finalized, and is mostly used for sensitive transactions to be totally sure it won't be rolled back.

Since you need to access the new state immediately, try changing your commitment to `Confirmed` instead. That way you shouldn't need to wait more than a second or two.